# What and with what was Luthor doing in the ship at the end of the movie?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

After Doomsday was defeated, a spec-ops team sent to the Kryptionian ship in Metropolis found Luthor submerged in water, in front of a... thing, which "held" three metal cubes. The thing looked up, roars, and dissipates into thin air.

[image: ???]

What the hell was that all about? I am really confused. What was that creature and what was Luthor doing with it?

Comment: Related question from M&TV [Who was the horned creature luthor was seen with in Batman V Superman: Ultimate Edition?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56225/who-was-the-horned-creature-luthor-was-seen-with-in-batman-v-superman-ultimate)

Comment: He was ringing the bell

Comment: Ding ding ding ding ding

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think your answer on the related question is a better answer than the two current answers.

Comment: @Kalissar Thanks for the appreciation but i am not invested enough to post a competing answer for now but if anyone what to use  my answer they are free to sue it with proper attribution. Or you can give some love to my answer on Movies.se ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's definitely a better answer than mine! Added a small reference to it in my _answer_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who is this guy in Zack Snyder's Batman v Superman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123573/who-is-this-guy-in-zack-snyders-batman-v-superman)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### We really don't know.

It's likely that demonic looking creature is some servant of [Darkseid](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Darkseid), but we don't know for sure.

It could be [Yuga Khan](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Yuga_Khan_(New_Earth)) (Darkseid's father), or [Steppenwolf](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Steppenwolf_(Prime_Earth)) (a genral in Darkseid's army). Both wear long horned helmets, but neither really look like the creature we see in that scene. But whatever tech is being used seems to be only displaying an approximation of whoever Lex is talking to, so they probably look very different at the other end of that communication.

Those boxes are very likely [Mother boxes](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box), like the one we see in the Cyborg scene earlier in the movie. They are crazy advanced [New Gods](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/New_Gods) tech used for all sort of things. But, if that creature is a servant of Darkseid, those boxes could be [Father boxes](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fatherbox), which are Darkseid's version of the Mother box.

Why Lex is attempting to communicate with the creature is a mystery. He could be promising earth to Darkseid in exchange for power of protection? We don't know yet.

---

Ankit Sharma's answer over on the Movie Exchange is *(some might say)* superior to mine :)

Worth a look:

[Who was the horned creature luthor was seen with in Batman V Superman: Ultimate Edition?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56228/17983)

Answer (score 0):

That was supposedly Steppenwolf. Those were Motherboxes probably. And it was likely Luthor being stupid, trying to get Apokaliptan technology which he and intergang try to do in multiple continuities.

Other than that, if we knew more, or even the above for sure, the next movie would already be out or it would be ruined by it already having all it's info revealed.

Comment: Can you provide any sources to back up your claims?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ultimately it comes down to the same source that others have provided, Snyder for that it is Steppenwolf even though they don't look alike. That the objects are Mother/Father boxes could be checked against the Cyborg scene's Motherbox to see if they look the same. All that we know that Luthor was doing is contacting Apokalips from within Zod's ship... which makes no sense on any level, but if the interaction remains consistant with comics this is the only thing Lex ever really does with Apokalips. And it is obviously the next movie isn't out yet...